# React v18 + Material UI v5 + Weback 5 : Not working when create as npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, tsconfig, webpack-5

I am trying to create simple react package that can be used in react apps.
I am using these main libraries: React(18.2.0), Webpack(5.4.0), mui/material(5.11.2), typescript(4.9.4).

I am adding this package in my react app using local dependency("packagename": "file:../package").

It is working fine without mui. But when i add mui it's building fine in package but gives error in react app where package is used.

Below is webpack configurations of package.

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = (env) => ({
  mode: env.NODE_ENV,
  watch: env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "libname",
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        options: {
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"),
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                auto: true,
                localIdentName:
                  env.NODE_ENV === "development"
                    ? "[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
                    : "[hash:base64:5]",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        include: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "@svgr/webpack",
            options: {
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.STAGE": JSON.stringify(env.STAGE),
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ],
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: "react",
      commonjs2: "react",
      amd: "react",
      root: "React",
    },
    "react-dom": {
      commonjs: "react-dom",
      commonjs2: "react-dom",
      amd: "react-dom",
      root: "ReactDOM",
    },
  },
});
```

This is package.config.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.42",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/index.js",
    "dist/index.d.ts",
    "dist/*.png",
    "dist/*.jpg"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

Below is tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
```

I am getting below error in react app in which package is used. That reach app is created using create-react-app and using latest react v18.
[image]

I tried researching and tried by changing several options in webpack config as well. But i am not able to figure this out.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

React 18 introduces a new root API, Change your index.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

For Typescript:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Where do i add this? In package or the react app where package is being added/imported?

Comment: React app, In your file index.js.

Comment: Was there confusion to this answer? I suppose there was hence the bounty. What were you trying to figure out?

Comment: This doesn't work at all. It doesn't solve the issue. You are lucky that i was busy with other stuff and was not able to try this out hence bounty got auto awarded.